# How to change width of wizard in Odoo 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, odoo, odoo-8

Is there a way to change the wizard width for a specific wizards class in Odoo? 
I've created a css file to increase the width into a special div that odoo create when the window popup is rendered, with `class="modal-content openerp"` but all the wizards in Odoo had been changed. I just want to change the width for a certain `TransientModel`. Is it possible?

Comment: i think in css you can select element it have special child just add empty div with special class to the form of the wizard and target the parent of that div what do you think ?

Comment: @Charif, I tried to add a css class to the form, but that doesn't change window popup width. Using the developer mode in chrome browser i found  a special div with css class="modal-content openerp" if i change the width in this level  the wizard dimention change, but between this special div and my form there is 10 level of elements, and all of them were created dynamically, so how we can target 10 level of parent from a child (i think the solution is only in JQuery  because in CSS is imposible)

Answer (score 3):

Adapting the solution of @Marcel to Odoo 11 to almost fill the browser window:

```
<record id="your_wizard_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">your wizard name</field>
    <field name="model">your wizard model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="....." version="7.0">
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.modal-dialog').css({'width': '97%', 'height': '97%'});
                $('.modal-content').css({'height': '100%'});
                $('.modal-body').css({'height': '100%'});
            });
        </script>

        <!-- rest of the form -->

    </form>
</field>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change the size of a wizard by following way:

```
<record id="your_wizard_id" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">your wizard name</field>
    <field name="model">your wizard model</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="....." version="7.0">
        <sheet>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('.ui-dialog').css({'width': '680px'});
                    $('.oe_form_sheet_width').css({'MAXwidth': '550px'});
                    });
            </script>
        </sheet>
    </form>
</field>
```

Hope this helps you.